# Is there a way to only send matching media queries in server response?

Tags: css, optimization, server

I have a large amount of mobile CSS and a large amount of desktop CSS, and I'd rather not be sending them both along when only half of the media queries match any given client.

Is there any way to figure out in advance which media queries will match and send only that portion of the CSS?

Comment: You could try to check the user agent and try to guess if the browser is desktop or mobile and return 2 different css files but you'll have a lot of bad detections. Anyway, if you have that much difference I suggest you really think how you are styling your site. If you want users to have a consistent experience on your site on multiple devices then you should have a lot of CSS in common and only media queries to adjustments.

Comment: Also, how much is "a large amount"? Maybe you are overoptimizing, if you use caching then you may only need to download css files once until you change something, you can minify it, you can gzip it, you have better techniques to reduce the file size.

Comment: I would user server-side browser sniffing as an absolute last resort. It can be difficult to maintain and is very unpredictable. Some vendors purposefully make it difficult to detect the difference between their desktop and mobile counterparts, and the size of the browser window is never guaranteed to be maximized (eg, my current browser is 700px wide, smaller than most tablets.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is as old as responsive design. The easiest (but most incorrect) way to do this is to have some sort of empty page which loads the styles and content for the device. This is incorrect because it it spits in the face of accessibility, crawlability (bots), and user experience (page takes longer to load as compared to server-side rendered site).

The way I have solved this in the past is to separate my site/app into three parts

1. the "shell" (header, nav, footer, overall layout)
2. the "meat" (the content users and search engines want)
3. everything else (ads, asides, non-critical content)

You want to render the "shell" and the "meat" on the server along with a minimal set of styles to make it render something without making any extra requests. These styles should include a minimal set of `@media` queries for rendering the site/app in a crudely responsive manner.

Next, using JavaScript which is embedded on the page, you want to hide the "meat" of the site so that it's not visible. You want to show a loading indicator so that users know you are loading something. The "shell" should always be visible as this gives the user a sense that your site is half way through loading. At this point, you can load your remaining styles and content.

Once the styles and extra content is loaded you can hide the loader and reveal your styled content. At this point, you can load any non-critical content or ads. Here's a basic layout:

```
<head>
  <style>
    /* 
    include core styles and base media queries 
    for high-level layout and theming
    */

    html,
    body,
    main {
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* include loader styles here */
    .loader {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="logo.png" />
    <nav>Home | About | Sign In</nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <script>
      // use JavaScript to show the loader and hide the main content
        document.write('<div class="loader">/* spinner gif */</div>');
    </script>

    <!-- Meat of the page - initially hidden by the loader -->
  </main>

  <footer>
    <!-- Footer content -->
  </footer>

  <script>
    /* 
    Load the rest of your app here. This should include
    styles for the current device, extra content, etc.

    After the styles and content are loaded, hide the loader
    so the user can start using the site/app. At that point
    start loading ads and other non-critical content.
    */
  </script>
</body>
```